# How to move to next line while reading a text file in oracle using PL-SQL when any exception occurs?

Tags: oracle, text, plsql, feed, utl-file

The motive is to keep the procedure running even after exception occurs.

I have a code which is used to process feed (text) files.

The moment it reaches an exception it logs it into a temporary error table and
tries to roll back to the savepoint stated earlier in the code.

However, i want to skip the line with the error in it and continue with the procedure execution. here is the code snippet.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE
    PROCEDURE ABC AS
    FHANDLE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    BUFFER VARCHAR2(32767);
    ROW_NO NUMBER;
    ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2(50);
    ERROR_MSG VARCHAR2(299);
    CUST_ID TABLE1.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE;
    B_ACCOUNT_NO TABLE1.BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO%TYPE;
    UB_OUT TABLE1.OUTSTANDING_UNBILLED_AMOUNT%TYPE;
    BA_COUNT NUMBER;
    DEL1 NUMBER;
    DEL2 NUMBER;
    DEL3 NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    FHANDLE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR1','FILENAME.txt','R',4096);
    ROW_NO := 0;
    ERROR_CODE:= '';
    ERROR_MSG := '';
    LOOP
    BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(FHANDLE,BUFFER);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    EXIT;
    END;
    SAVEPOINT S1;
    --GETTING DELIMITER POSITIONS
    DEL1 := INSTR(BUFFER,'|',1,1);
    DEL2 := INSTR(BUFFER,'|',1,2);
    DEL3 := INSTR(BUFFER,'|',1,3);
    ROW_NO := ROW_NO +1 ;
    --RETRIEVING DATA FROM TEXT FILE INTO VARIABLES
    B_ACCOUNT_NO := SUBSTR(BUFFER,1,DEL1-1);
    CUST_ID := SUBSTR(BUFFER,DEL1+1,DEL2-DEL1-1);
    UB_OUT := SUBSTR(BUFFER,DEL2+1);
    --CHECK FOR PRESENCE OF BILLING ACCOUNT
    SELECT COUNT(BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO) INTO BA_COUNT FROM TABLE1 WHERE  CUSTOMER_ID = CUST_ID AND BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO = B_ACCOUNT_NO;
    --IF PRESENT THEN UPDATE
    IF BA_COUNT != 0
    THEN
    UPDATE TABLE1
    SET OUTSTANDING_UNBILLED_AMOUNT = UB_OUT
    WHERE BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO = B_ACCOUNT_NO AND CUSTOMER_ID = CUST_ID;
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO TABLE1(CUSTOMER_ID,BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO,OUTSTANDING_BILLED_AMOUNT,OUTSTANDING_UNBILLED_AMOUNT)
VALUES(CUST_ID,B_ACCOUNT_NO,0,UB_OUT);
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL_ROWS_READ : '||ROW_NO);
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(FHANDLE);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERROR_MSG := SQLERRM;
    CWSC_ERROR_PROC(ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MSG,ROW_NO,CUST_ID,B_ACCOUNT_NO,'','');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHERS EXCEPTION');
    --log into error table
    ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERROR_MSG := SQLERRM;
    --THIS PROCEDURE LOGS ERRORS INTO TEMPORARY ERROR LOG TABLE
    ERROR_PROC(ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MSG,ROW_NO,CUST_ID,B_ACCOUNT_NO,'','');
    ROLLBACK TO S1;

   << NEED CODE HERE TO SKIP CURRENT RECORD AND START EXECUTION FROM NEXT RECORD >>      

    END ABC;
```

The text file is somewhat like

```
1002207577 | 1002207576 | 0
1002201449 | 1002201446 | 0
1000000010 | 1000000010 | 0
1000000018 | 1000000098 | 0
1000000023 | 1000000073 | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create inner `BEGIN - EXCEPTION - END` block and place your code and exception handler there. It that case you will finish only inner block and continue with outer

Example:

```
DECLARE
  n NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First n='||n);
  BEGIN
    n:= 'Hello';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not a number');
  END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Finally n='||n);
END;
```